# Extjs 5.1 Dynamic addition of container to panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

What i am trying to do is dynamically add container to panel on click of button.

1st instance of container gets added and can be seen in the panel.items.length

2nd instance onwards the panel.items.length doesn't change. but the panel can be seen in dom and on screen.

Just wanted to know why the panel.items.length is not increasing. Is it a bug?

Fiddler link https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/p3u

Check for the line :

> console.log(qitems);

below debugger; it is set to questionsblock.items.length that i am talking about.

Comment: Suggest you read the docs about `renderTo`. "Do not use this option if the Component is to be a child item of a Container. It is the responsibility of the Container's layout manager to render and manage its child items."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the itemId from QuestionTemplate and remove renderTo from the new instance.

Your click handler should look like this:

```
listeners: {
    'click': function(button) {
        var questionPanel = button.up('form').down('#questionsblock'),
            qitems = questionPanel.items.length,
            questiontemplate = Ext.create('QuestionTemplate', {
            qid: qitems,
            questiontype: 'text'
        });
        console.log(qitems);
        questionPanel.add(questiontemplate);
        questionPanel.doLayout();
    }
}
```

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/p47

Comment: thanks, the solution you gave did fixed my problem. thanks once again.